# Perfect map: If $Y$ is compact, then $X$ is compact?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, proof-explanation, compactness

I am trying to understand this proof and  everything was  pretty well until the last part of the second paragraph.

...Since $Y$ is compact, we can choose a finite subcover $W_{y_1},...,W_{y_m}$ covering $Y$. **Then the collection $V_{y_1},...,V_{y_m}$** covers $X$...

I am having difficulties understanding the bold text.

I have done this to try to understand it. 
$$f(V_y)=\bigcup_{j=1}^mf(U_{i_j})\supset\bigcup_{i=1}^m W_{y_i}=Y=f(X)...(1)$$
  $$X=\bigcup_{i=1}^mV_{y_i}...(2)$$

My question is how do you pass  form (1) to (2) ?

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that in the second part the phrase:

"the sets $p(V_{y})$ each contain some open neighborhood $W_y$ of $y$..."

must be replaced by the stronger statement:

"for every set $V_{y}$ we can find an open neighborhood of $W_y$ of $y$ such that $p^{-1}(W_{y})\subseteq V_{y}$...".

---

Let $x\in X$.

Then $p(x)\in Y=\bigcup_{i=1}^m W_{y_i}$ so $p(x)\in W_{y_i}$ for some $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$.

Then $x\in p^{-1}(W_{y_i})\subseteq V_{y_i}$ because the $W_{y_i}$ are chosen in such a way that $p^{-1}(W_{y_i})\subseteq V_{y_i}$.

The fact that is is possible has been proved in the first part.

Proved is now that the sets $V_{y_1},\dots V_{y_m}$ cover $X$.

Comment: the U and V were confusing me, why was U here $p^{-1}(W_y)\subset U$ instead of $V$ ?

Comment: the author started with open cover $(U_{\alpha})$. Maybe it would have been less confusing to start with open cover $(V_{\alpha})$. After that $U_y$ appear and then the analogy with the first part would be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

$X=p^{-1}(Y)=\cup_{i=1}^{i=m}p^{-1}(W_{y_i})$ since $p^{-1}(W_{y_i})\subset V_{y_i}$, you deduce that $X= \cup_{i=1}^{i=m}V_{y_i}$.

Comment: In the proof is $V_{y_i}$ not $U_{y_i}$